# git commit command with core.editor equals atom

Tags: git, atom-editor

I have a problem with atom editor. I set atom as the core.editor by command:

```
git config --global core.editor atom
```

But when I try to commit the changes to a repository in git by

```
git commit
```

command, I expects that the editor of my choice will open and prompt for the commit message but before it opens git throws an error

```
Aborting commit due to empty commit message.
```

after it it opens the editor and when I enter the commit message and quits the editor no commit occurs, I know I can use command

```
git commit -m '<message>'
```

but I want to know why this error occurs and how to solve it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try with:

```
git config --global core.editor "atom --wait"
```

the atom **--wait** flag wait for window to be closed before returning.

Comment: Didn't worked for me on MacOS BigSur with zsh!!

Comment: @iCantC this works for me: `git config --global core.editor "/Applications/Atom.app/Contents/Resources/app/atom.sh -n -w"`