# Making Atom wait before commiting

Tags: git, github, atom-editor

I am new to Github and I encountered the following problem. When I try to commit a file (I am using the Atom editor) the Command Line displays the following message:

`hint: Waiting for your editor to close the file...
Aborting commit due to empty commit message.`

I have configured atom with the following command `git config --global core.editor` atom -wait 
however nothing changes. Any help would be welcomed

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/37706443/1256452 suggests `--wait`, not just `-wait`; does that make a difference? (I use neither Windows nor atom.)

Comment: No, unfortunately, it nothing changed. Thanks though